# Position layout view to the top

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have created a profile creation page, where user respond to a variety of questions. My issue is that when the application is loaded the layout is not display from the top. In the sense that you have to scroll up to the see the field on top. I think the issue may resolve around the edit text headline (etxheadline), where when the activity load, it seems to be focused into it.

Thanks in advance

Below is the layout code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dark_texture_blue" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="797dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtname"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#330099"
        android:text="Upload from Facebook"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:text="Select photo from gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Preferred Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please type your age here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="Please type your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:text="Female" />

    </RadioGroup>

     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:hint="A quick description of yourself"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Search Distance (100KM)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tMaxAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Headline"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tMaxAge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMaximumAge"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="50"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="I agree to the terms and Conditions"
            android:textColor="#D2D2D2"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView16"
             android:layout_width="280dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Click here to review the terms and conditions"
             android:textColor="#99CCFF"
             android:textSize="16sp" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnReset"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
             android:alpha="0.8"
             android:background="#660000"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:text="Reset"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="17sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
             android:alpha="0.8"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
             android:background="#330099"
             android:text="Confirm"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="17sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update
Activity code**

```
 public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);
        ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollProfile);
        s.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

        Parse.initialize(this, "SBNldSjuNL1F7IOj0OWpwenBWRF7rSkjkm8WFQJj", "DLvq1OqSo87kzEw5j1XNBPKJdXF7dxwRtfEPkxWJ");

        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);

        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();


                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 
                    currentUser.put("name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
        if (!picturePath.equals("")) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Locate the image in res > 
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                Object image = null;
                try {
                    String path = null;
                    image = readInFile(path);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create the ParseFile
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", (byte[]) image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground();

                // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
                ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

                // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");


                // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

                // Create the class and the columns
                imgupload.saveInBackground();

                // Show a simple toast message


            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it progmatically using the `ScrollView` instance.

You need to add an **id** in your `ScrollView` and use that instance somewhere in your activity/fragment class then scroll up the scrollview to the top

**sample:**

```
ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
s.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and clarification. I have added the code into my activity class, but the problem still persist, so I am not too sure what to do from now. Hence, I have updated my initial post with the activity code included under the update section of my post, and have edited my XML page. If you could kindly assist me on this matter, that would be helpful.

Comment: @user3827788 try s.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I tried s.scrollTo(0, 0), but unfortunately the issue pertains.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following ,

```
 ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
 s.scrollTo(0,s.getTop());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately the problem persist. Maybe the issues resolves around my XML (included in my initial post).